# How do I make a resizing background image in css?

Tags: css, html

What I have so far is:

```
body {
    background-image: url("image file");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I have found an answer look below.

Comment: what do you mean by resizing background? the background will resize as you change the size of the browser or you can resize the background with mouse?

Comment: I mean I want the image to always be fully visible on the screen while the browser is changing sizes. the full image not just part of it as the window changes

Comment: @alexroberts Are you wanting the image to stretch to cover the visible area? Or are you wanting the image to retain its dimensions? If you have a tile with which you want to cover the screen remove `background-image: no-repeat` from your code. Otherwise, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

With `background-size:cover`, the background will automatically scale with the size of its parent element to cover the entire thing.

In this case, for it to scale larger or smaller, you can set width and height on your body element.

Comment: if I resize the window it will move the text to the upper right corner of the image

Comment: What do you mean? There's no part of the post that mentioned text.

Comment: To move text in the body, you can add the property for `text-align`, where you can set it as `center`, `left`, or `right`, based on where you want it

Comment: I don't know very much about this yet I'm probably just saying this all wrong ill figure it out thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Comment: this is what I want but all that's wrong is if the window is too big then the image wont stretch. and part of the screen will be white.

Comment: I've updated the answer, I think it is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Stretch horizontally and vertically:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Stretch horizontally (preserve image ratio):

```
background-size: 100%;
background-size: 100% auto; /* This is the same as above (included so you can see the similarities below). */
```

Stretch vertically (preserve image ratio):

```
background-size: auto 500px; /* If you use percentage (100%), you must set the height of the containing element. */
```

Comment: what if you only want to stretch it vertically?

Comment: @alexroberts You can stretch vertically by manipulating the second value of the `background-size` property. For example, use `background-size: 100% 800px;` if you want to keep the width at 100% but stretch the image vertically to a size of 800 pixels.

Comment: thank you but what is the difference between contain and initial

Comment: @alexroberts `background-size: initial;` will set the image to it's original size (no stretching or shrinking). I do not recommend using it, as it is not supported by Internet Explorer, and it's usually unnecessary. On the other hand, `background-size: contain;` will expand the size of the image until it reaches its element's `width` or `height` (whichever comes first).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer all I had to do was modify one of your answers

```
body {background-image: url("image file");
background-size: 110% 130%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

thank you for all your help.